# Remove everything outside of string including string

Tags: notepad++

I would like to remove:
- everything outside a string (eg. `<Word>`);
- the string itself;

And keep only the phrase that was between the string.

See below:

Source data:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <Word>consectetur</Word> adipiscing elit. In non porta nulla. Praesent auctor tellus sit amet libero auctor interdum. Morbi pulvinar, lorem vel volutpat scelerisque, orci magna rhoncus est, tempus <Word>sollicitudin</Word> metus ligula vitae eros. Phasellus ultricies blandit <Word>felis nec</Word> malesuada. Nulla quis neque efficitur, suscipit lacus vitae, ornare massa. <Word>Proin</Word> at blandit enim, nec vulputate leo. Aliquam sed nisl in <Word>nibh placerat</Word> fringilla.
```

Resultant:

```
consectetur
sollicitudin
felis nec
Proin
nibh placerat
```

Comment: I've tried: Find what:          \</Word>.*?<Word>
Replace with:       
Wrap around:        checked
Regular expression: selected
. matches newline:  checked - no luck

Comment: replace with nothing.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/624518/delete-text-before-and-after-a-specific-character-in-notepad - this is almost it, but it has problems since there are mulitple <word> strings in each line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Find-what zone:** `(?s)(?:.*?<Word>(.+?)</Word>)|(?!.+?<Word>).+`

**Replace-with zone:** `(?1\1\r\n)`

**Search mode:** Regular expression